# Incompatible input to LSTM layer in TF.Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tf.keras

I am trying to run a LSTM on some text data I have embedded.

The input I have is of shape `(training_set_size, paragraph_length, embedding_dimension)`

The output is a vector of integers from 0-31 representing one of 32 possible labels, each word being labeled. It is of shape `(training_set_size, paragraph_length, 1)`

Before I added embedding, this was working with a few slight tweaks.
Back then, the shape of my inputs was `(training_set_size, paragraph_length, 1)` and the input_shape for the LSTM layer was `(paragraph_length, 1)`

My problem is that I am getting one of two errors, and solving one seems to cause the other.

Here is my code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, input_shape = (input_len, embedding_dim), return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32))
])

model.compile('adam', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

The above code yields the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 100)

---

So I have tried to change the shape of the LSTM input:

```
input_shape = (input_len, embedding_dim, 1)
```

This instead yields the following different error:

> Input 0 of layer lstm_8 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 1000, 100, 1]

EDIT: `training_set_size=17744`, `paragraph_length=1000`, and `embedding_dim=100`

Comment: What is the actual shape of your training input? You claim it is (training_set_size, paragraph_length, embedding_dimension), but in reality it is (1000, 100).

Comment: training_set_size=17744, paragraph_lenth =1000, and embedding_dim=100. It is being passed in one example at a time, and each example is of shape (1000,100).

Comment: Then that is the problem, you are removing the batch dimension, even a single sample should have a batch dimension of 1

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. How can I make sure it has the batch dimension of  1? When I include batch_size=1 as an argument to either model.fit or model.evaluate, I still get the first error. If I try to specify the shape of the input to the layer as (1,1000,100), where (batch_size=1, timesteps=1000,features=100), I still get get the second error.